# Scrollbar for single-line TextBox?

Tags: winforms

I want a WinForms TextBox to just have one line, but I want it to have a horizontal scrollbar so that it is immediately obvious when the text exceeds the size, and makes it easy to see where you are in it and move around.  What's the easiest and/or best way to do this?  Scrollbars only seem to appear if you set `.Multiline = true`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is baked-in behavior of the native Window edit control.  Forcing the WS_HSCROLL style bit on makes no difference, it doesn't show the horizontal scrollbar anyway.  Somewhat defensible, it would look quite ugly.  It isn't much of a practical problem, the user knows what she just entered in the box.